# View controller wont be pushed

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I cant seem to push this view controller and I must be doing something wrong. Code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(pushToStart) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)pushToStart
{
ViewController *view = [[ViewController alloc]init];

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:view animated:YES];

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a navigationController? If you add `NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController);` in `pushToStart` what do you see in your console?

Comment: @deanWombourne (null). how do I set one up?

Comment: You need to create a navigation controller in IB and link your view controller to it as the root view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a UINavigationController programatically, or do it using Interface Builder - There are 100's of tutorials online on how to do this. For example [here](http://youtu.be/EK498fPy0cc)